# What is the fastest data structure to search and update list of integer values?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I have to maintain a list of unordered integers , where number of integers are unknown. It may increase or decrease over the time. I need to update this list of integers frequently. I have tried using vector . But it is really slow . Array appears to be faster , but since the length of list is not fixed, it takes significant amount of time to resize it . Please suggest any other option .

Comment: I tend to like this picture : http://www.liamdevine.co.uk/code/images/container.png

Comment: Have you considered using sorted/search trees?

Comment: Can you be more clear about your requirements?  What exactly does "updating" consist of?

Comment: Have you considered an `std::unordered_map<int, T>` ? It would seem a good fit for your requirements.

Comment: What does *unordered* mean in your eyes ? Is the absence of order important, do you not care about the order at all, or should they be ordered by another criteria than their value (ie, always push the latest at the back) ? (and of course, what Benjamin asked, what does update mean to you) => I advise writing an example: take 5/6 integers and show what operations you want: `[1, 3, 4, 2]`, I add 5: `[1, 3, 4, 5, 2]`, I transform 4 into 6: `[1, 6, 3, 5, 2]`...

Comment: If you do not update to often you can `std::sort` the `std::vector` and use `std::lower_bound` to find the element.

Comment: Arrays are faster than `vector`s? They are the same thing?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley updating means :- suppose list contains values 1-5. now a new set of values came( 4,5,7) so only 7 will be added to list. 4 and 5 wont be added as they are already present in list.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I do not care about the order at all,

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I dont know exact reason but while handling 3d mesh data i found using native array is extreemly fast compared to std vector or qvector

Answer (score 1):

Use a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), if order of the values in unimportant.  Time is O(1).  I'm pretty sure you'll find an implementation in the standard template libraries.

Failing that, a [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) is extremely fast, especially if you want to keep the list ordered: amortized cost of O(ln n) per operation, with a very low constant factor.  I think  C++ stdlib map is something like this.

Know thy data structures.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in Dynamic increments of Arrays size you can do this .

```
current =0;
x = (int**)malloc(temp * sizeof(int*));
x[current]=(int*)malloc(RequiredLength * sizeof(int));
```

So add elements to array and when elements are filled in x[current] 
You can add more space for elements by doing

```
x[++current]=(int*)malloc(RequiredLength * sizeof(int));
```

Doing this you can accommodate for **RequiredLength** more elements .

You can repeat this upto 1024 times which means **1024*RequiredLength** elements can be

accommodated , here it gives you chance to increase size of array whenever you want it .

You can always access the n th element by X[ n / 1024 ][ n % 1024] ;

Answer (score 1):

Considering your comments, it looks like it is `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` fits your needs better than `std::vector`.

Comment: The one issue one could have with `std::set` (and `std::unordered_set`) is about the memory; a `std::vector` is extremely compact in memory so highly suitable for small collections.

Comment: @MatthieuM. : You are right, but the thread opener should decide whether to trade memory for speed or vice versa. From the comments I would assume, that it is the inserting operation causing the performance problems when looking for duplicates (searching in Vector is O(n) in set it is O(log n)

Comment: I agree; the question is clearly lacking... Actually, I upvoted your answer because it recommends the containers with the best semantics for the problem at hand; measures will tell whether they perform well enough...

Answer (score 0):

If sequential data structures fails to meet requirements, you could try looking at trees (binary, AVL, m-way, red-black ect ...). I would suggest you try to implement AVL tree since it yields a balanced or near balanced binary search tree which would optimize your operation. For more on AVL tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree

Answer (score 0):

well,deque has no resize cost,but if it's unordered,it's search time is linear ，and its delete and insert operation time in the middle of its self is even worth than vector.
  if you don't need search by the value of the number,hashmap or map may be your choice .No resize cost.,then you set the key of the map to number's index,and the value to the number's value.the search and insert operation is better than linear.

Answer (score -1):

std::list is definitely created for such problems, adding and deleting elements in list do not necessitate memory re-allocations like in vector. However, due to the noncontagious memory allocation of the list, searching elements may prove to be a painful experience ofcourse but if you do not search its entries frequently, it can be used.

Comment: It would seem to me this goes well-beyond-horrible in fulfilling the "search" part of the OP's requirements for performance.